# How PAM determines system password and 2FA OTP

Tags: linux, pam, google

I configured freeradius+google auth otp

Below are content of /etc/pam.d/radiusd

```
auth requisite pam_google_authenticator.so 
forward_pass auth required pam_unix.so use_first_pass
```

I was wondering how pam differentiates systempassword and otp code "s3cretpAss77123456" and use to authenticate against correct password combination since there are not delimiters in between those two passwords.

Answer (score 0):

The Google authentication modifies the password.  The codes are a fixed length so it can strip the correct number of characters from the password when it authenticates the code.  This way other modules are never confused by seeing the extra characters.

The password is then passed to other modules without the code appended.

PAM itself has no idea that there are two passwords in the same string.

Comment: am i correct if i understand like this - ' the google pam module strips the last 6 chars from password+otp combination ...and rest of things in authentication continue'

Comment: Almost right. It does some verification agains 8 digit by trying both. Take a look at https://github.com/google/google-authenticator-libpam/blob/master/src/pam_google_authenticator.c